# ItemCommand on nested Repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a simple aspx page which contains 2 nested repeaters.  Each of these have buttons on them.  When the user clicks on a button on the outer repeater, I can capture the ItemCommand in my codebehind, however when the user clicks on an inner one, I cannot capture it.

I have read in other threads about needing to attach the event manually to the inner repeater, but cannot work this out.

Can anyone help?

Here is the aspx.  I'm using vb.net code behind

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ParentRepeater">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <li id="P<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")%>">
            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.name")%>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="adedit" Text="Edit" CommandName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")%>'
                class="pages-edit" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="addel" Text="Delete" CommandName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.xid")%>'
                class="pages-delete" />
            <ul class="page-section sub innerdrag">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="childrepeater">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li id="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")%>,">
                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.name")%><asp:Button runat="server" ID="ad_edit"
                                Text="Edit" CommandName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.id")%>' class="pages-edit" />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ad_del" Text="Delete" CommandName='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.xid")%>'
                                class="pages-delete" />
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Still not firing so I've put the updated VB here too

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim DBFunctions As New DBFunctions.Functions
            Dim dstmp As New DataSet
            Dim dstmp2 As New DataSet
            dstmp = DBFunctions.SQLDataSet("SELECT id,name, 'x'+cast(id as varchar(50)) as xid from pages where parent = 0 and coalesce(active,1)=1 order by orderby asc", "data")
            dstmp2 = DBFunctions.SQLDataSet("SELECT id,name , 'x'+cast(id as varchar(50)) as xid,parent from pages where parent >0 and coalesce(active,1)=1 order by orderby asc", "data2")
            Dim allData As New DataSet
            allData.Tables.Add(dstmp.Tables(0).Copy)
            allData.Tables.Add(dstmp2.Tables(0).Copy)
            allData.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("Children", allData.Tables(0).Columns("ID"), allData.Tables(1).Columns("parent")))
            ParentRepeater.DataSource = allData
            ParentRepeater.DataBind()
            sdhfunctions.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub repMenu1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles ParentRepeater.ItemDataBound
        Dim dv As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
        If dv IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim repSubMenu As Repeater = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("childrepeater"), Repeater)
            If repSubMenu IsNot Nothing Then
                AddHandler repSubMenu.ItemCommand, AddressOf childrepeater_ItemCommand
                repSubMenu.DataSource = dv.CreateChildView("Children")
                repSubMenu.DataBind()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
    Protected Sub ParentRepeater_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles ParentRepeater.ItemCreated
        Dim dv As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
        If dv IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim repSubMenu As Repeater = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("childrepeater"), Repeater)
            If repSubMenu IsNot Nothing Then
                AddHandler repSubMenu.ItemCommand, AddressOf childrepeater_ItemCommand
                repSubMenu.DataSource = dv.CreateChildView("Children")
                repSubMenu.DataBind()
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub childrepeater_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
        Dim stophere As String = ""
    End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint on stophere, and it never gets hit.

Sorry guys, I'm really confused :(

Comment: Is this the real code you are using? There seems to be no subscription to the outer's Repeater ItemCommand event

Comment: The itemcommend is on the buttons on the parent repeater, and I can capture thes in codebehind.  However I cannot capture the itemcommand on the inner repeater buttons.

Comment: Why would you ever want to capture this in code behind? What's wrong with just `<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="childrepeater" OnItemCommand="childrepeater_ItemCommand">` ?

Comment: I need to capture a unique reference against the button which is clicked.  Hence I put it in the itemcommand

Comment: Very nice, but you already have this in place, and the event handler subscription is not supposed to have this information anyway. I still don't get it, to be honest

Comment: Dude, did you get this resolved?

Comment: Nope, I'm on a short timescale so I've handled it with a bit of Javascript which will capture the ID of the button being clicked and then trigger a postback.  However, I'd like to be able to do it "correctly" and handle it all on the server as described in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Protected Sub ParentRepeater_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles ParentRepeater.ItemCreated
    Dim childRepeater As Repeater = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("childrepeater"), Repeater)
    AddHandler childRepeater.ItemCommand, AddressOf childrepeater_ItemCommand
    childRepeater.DataSource = "the data source for childRepeater"
    childRepeater.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub childrepeater_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: I have converted this to VB.net  and tried it, however I still cannot capture the itemcommand on the buttons on the inner repeater.

This is what it became ` Protected Sub ParentRepeater_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

Dim childRepeater As Repeater = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("childrepeater"), Repeater)
AddHandler childRepeater.ItemCreated, AddressOf Childrepeater_ItemCommand
End Sub

 Private Sub childrepeater_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs)

        Dim stophere As String = ""

    End Sub`

Comment: Sorry, I was paying my mistake for the C#. Let me get that answer for you.

Comment: Sorry, can't get the code to format in my comment.  I hate web dev lol (apart from the fact it pays my bills!!)

Comment: This should get you what you want. I forgot that without actually binding (Databind()) childRepeater, ItemCommand won't fire. Now it should.

Comment: You're almost there - you need to add the [`Handles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx) clause to the end of the `Sub` definition, like so: `Protected Sub ParentRepeater_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles ParentRepeater.ItemCommand`.  There may be different command events so be careful what you select.